# React with Windows Authentication

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I've got an intranet-based Web API that I will be securing with windows authentication, but how do I also secure the front end in terms of showing only certain actions to users with a certain role?

For example in MVC I could have done something like this in the view:

```
if (User.IsInRole("SecureRoleA") == true)
 ...show button <button></button>
}
```

But in react:

1. I won't have access to `User.IsInRole` and
2. any code that I write like that would be viewable in the javascript file which doesn't seem very secure (even if the server should also check they have access).

What is the recommended approach here? Should I send the groups the user belongs to into react and maybe store it them in the local storage so check can be performed against that? Or is there a better method I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

You should use token and add extra data to return json:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken
                    (
                        issuer: _configuration["Issuer"],
                        audience: _configuration["Audience"],
                        claims: claims,
                        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(60),
                        notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey
                                (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["SigningKey"])),
                            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                    );
return Ok(new
                {
                    token,
                    fullName = user.FullName,
                    roles = role,
            });
```

and in react code check role access

Comment: Ok makes sense, thanks, Do you have any examples or links to how to create this toek with windows authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Any authorization code you write in the front-end will be for user experience only, not security.
Since as you said it will be visible, but also *editable* on the user device.
But it is definitely useful to hide buttons for features the user can't access anyway.

A common method has been to create a local JSON Web Token on login and send that to the UI app.
It can then be kept in local storage and sent with all requests.

Comment: Does the token apply to windows authentication too (as they don't actually login, it will be single sign on so they will just go straight to the app and be authenticated by IIS)? Thanks

Comment: Well, yeah it would essentially need to be an API endpoint your front-end calls when there is no user info or the token has expired.